# How to round the number in excel to its nearest real value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

In excel I want to change the decimal value to the nearest real value

```
15.5 -> 16
15.4-> 15
15.2-> 15
15.9-> 16
```

What formual I want to use if all these value in cell A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **[ROUND](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Round-Function.html)** formula:

For example to transform 15.5 into 16:

```
=ROUND(15.5,0)
```

Comment: and, just to note there is roundup() and rounddown() which can be handy as well.